# MIPS: Copy address of register to another register

Tags: assembly, mips

So I'm having trouble copying the address of a register to another register. Currently I'm doing this:

```
la $a2, $a0
```

And I'm getting a syntax error. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do registers have addresses?

Comment: @Mysticial They don't.

Comment: What's a rhetorical question? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to treat the contents of $ao as an address rather than a number, put it into () like this:

```
la $a2, ($a0)
```

You could also use the move instruction:

```
move $a2, $a0
```

Kevin

Comment: I think the OP expects the registers to be visible and accessible somewhere in the memory and have addresses. But the registers aren't mapped into the memory and have no memory addresses.

Answer (score 9):

MIPS registers do not have addresses.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the subtlety. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In some CPUs, registers actually reside in memory at some predefined locations and therefore have memory addresses. Registers in MIPS CPUs do not reside in memory and therefore do not have memory addresses.