# Difference in la and addi to copy a register in MIPS asm

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm new to MIPS and confused by a concept.

I have a value `5` stored in `$s5`, and I want to copy it to `$a0` so that I can use `li $v0, 1` to print it. I have two ways to copy.

1. `addi $a0, $s5, 0`
2. `la $a0, 0($s5)`

Either 1. or 2. can print the value `5` if I do `li $v0, 1` / `syscall` after it ([MARS's print-integer syscall](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html)).

But why does it work for 2.?   2. is storing the address of `$s5` at `$a0`, but we need a value, not an address.

Will this be automatically handled by print_integer?

Comment: Related: [MIPS: Copy address of register to another register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14993868) (confusing question because registers don't have memory addresses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `la` isn't a MIPS hardware instruction, just a pseudo-instruction implemented by the assembler, like `li`.  (Usually with `lui` / `addiu` to construct a 32-bit symbol address in a register, if you use it the normal way as `la  $reg, symbol`).  Look at disassembly / machine code output, e.g. like MARS shows you when you assemble.

You can abuse `la` as a `move` by using a register addressing mode instead of a symbol name.  (`move` is another pseudo-instruction; MIPS doesn't have a hardware move, you just add with `$zero` or an immediate `0`.)

**That `la` could assemble to exactly that `addi $a0, $s5, 0` if the assembler chose that**.  (Although more likely it would pick addiu; with an immediate other than 0 is has to not trap on signed overflow.  In general you never want add/addi, only addu/addiu.)

> 2 is storing the address of $s5 at $a0, but we need a value, not an address.
>   Will this be automatically handled by print_integer?

No, the value in `$a0` is identical either way, just like if you did `move $a0, $s5` like a normal person.  So there's no difference in the end result for print_integer to sort out.

You can't take the address of a register.  A register can *hold* a memory address, but you can't take the register's address.

Yes `la` "takes the address" of its source operand, but note that `0($s5)` isn't a register, it's the syntax for a memory addressing mode that refers to the memory at the address in `$s5`, like you could use with `lw`.  The address of that *memory* is just `$s5`.

**The C equivalent is `int *a0 = &*s5;`**  where the & cancels out the unary `*` dereference.